# How to ignore mutators and accessors when required

Tags: php, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I used Laraval's [Accessors and Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) to essentially overwrite the `group` column on my table by doing this on my model;

```
public function getGroupAttribute($value)
{
    if(config('app.pages.'.$value)) {
        return $value;
    }
    return "city";
}
```

So if `$value` is in the config, return `$value` else return the default.

That works fine. The only problem is now I am using [Maatwebsite](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export) to export the dataset I actually need the real value stored in the database. And at the moment, it doesn't do that, it only returns `group` after it's been "mutated" via the above method.

What can I do?

Comment: You can fetch model's data to array manually, and pass the array.

Comment: Can you? How? I think it will still go via the mutator

Comment: Mutators are being used by Eloquent, but Models are still php objects, so you can access them as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I think that override a standard property is not a good thing.

You can create your own mutator using a different name from the property, for example *getComputerGroupAttribute*, so you could use original members of the object when you need it.